# What is the benefit of using a PM200 cable to connect an EIZO monitor ta a macbook?

Tags: display, screen

My girlfriend bought an EIZO CG223W screen and uses it for now with my apple DVI-MiniDisplay-connector, when i don't need it. She could buy her own connector, but as well could buy a PM200 cable.

Now I'm a bit confused by the info on internet regarding the benefits of the PM200 cable vs. Apples DVI-MiniDisplay-connector:

1. the speed and color-quality/colordepth of the PM seems to be faster, but in realworld: how much will you notice?
2. can you use the monitors' USB-ports only with a PM200 cable?
3. can you daisy-chain a 3rd monitor only when using PM200?

(I have e-mailed Eizo already regarding this question, but didn't find an  answer yet.)

Answer (score 1):

Eizo (Netherlands) kindly and answered by e-mail. In short:

**for using this monitor with a macbook, there is no advantage using the PM200-cable compared to an Apple mini-display - DVI connector.**

More in detail:
(excuse me for poor english: I used google translate)

1. The PM200 is a cable DisplayPort cable. By using this cable you can use the EIZO CG223W-BK to give 10 bit per color (1025 tones per Red, Green or Blue). 10 Bit Color depth is as far as we know not possible on a Mac because the graphics cards do not support 10 Bit capability combined with Photoshop.
    
   To make display 10 bit color depth you should use this configuration:

   - Use OS or Windows 7 (older Windows OS)
   - Use DisplayPort
   - Use of good quality DisplayPort cable
   - Graphics card must support 10 bit
   - Application (software) must support 10 bit
   - Application requires graphics card with 10 bit support
      
     The application and the graphics card must therefore communicate in a certain way and we only know this possibility when using windows in combination with Photoshop CS6.
2. No, the PM200 cable can only be used as a signal cable (like the DVI cable). To use hard drives and printers via the monitor always be a USB cable required. To calibrate you have this USB connection is also required.
3. No, the monitor can not signal to another spot or third monitor. Serial looping will not go.